# Indefinite leave to remain sticker expired and traveled to India

Tags: united-kingdom

My son had an Indian passport with an indefinite leave to remain sticker on the passport. The validity matched the valid of the passport. I renewed his passport but didn't transfer the indefinite to remain, assuming there is no expiry date, but it expired along with the passport. Now I have travelled to India with my son. What am I supposed to do? How do I travel back?

Comment: As I understand it, the expiration of the sticker does not imply the expiration of the leave, since the latter is indefinite, but it does lapse under certain circumstances.  I'll leave it to someone who knows better than I do to answer your question specifically.  Do you have the expired passport with the old sticker?